# Google GSpread with Python: Merging my CSV files into a spreadsheet reads floats (0.232132) as integer (232132)

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets, gspread

I am merging some CSV files into one Google Spreadsheet (each CSV is a worksheet). The process itself works great, but I have many numeric values such as `0.12` which show in the new spreadsheet as `12`. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

My function to do this is (files is a list of the CSV files, spreadsheet is the spreadsheet I am saving the files to; the code, I think, is from another stackoverflow thread):

```py
def add_csv_files_to_spreadsheet(files, spreadsheet):
  # Generating a list of the sheet names saves API calls (less risk of exceeding the quota)
  worksheet_names = list()

  for file in files:
    filename = file.get("name")
    sheetName = filename.split(".")[0]
    sheet_id = file.get("id")
    downloaded_content = gdrive.CreateFile({'id' : sheet_id})
    downloaded_content.GetContentFile(filename) 
    content_df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype=str) # removing the dtype and using the decimal parameter both didn't help
    no_rows = len(content_df)
    no_cols = len(content_df.columns)
    
    worksheet = spreadsheet.add_worksheet(title=sheetName, rows = no_rows, cols = no_cols)
    gd.set_with_dataframe(worksheet, content_df)
    #worksheet = add_calculations(worksheet)
    worksheet_names.append(sheetName)

  # Delete Fragment from creation
  spreadsheet.del_worksheet(spreadsheet.sheet1)
```

And a csv dataframe can take up any forms! I assume I am just missing a setting but idk which one.

ETA:
I create the spreadsheet I use via code also, using this code:

```py
def create_spreadsheet(sheet_title, output_folder_id):
  """
  Create a new spreadsheet with the given title (sheet_title). Can be saved in a specific folder by giving the folder_id in a list
  """
  drive_api = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

  print("Creating Sheet %s", sheet_title)
  body = {
      'name': sheet_title,
      'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
  }

  if output_folder_id:
      body["parents"] =  output_folder_id

  req = drive_api.files().create(body=body)
  new_sheet = req.execute()
  
  return new_sheet["id"]
```

ETA 2: I solved the issue by changing my preferred language options on my GOOGLE PROFILE to canadian English (they use dots for decimal numbers, my original languages uses commas) but there gotta be an easier way?

Comment: So you tried to use `decimal=','` while using pandas in `content_df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype=str)` and the issue persisted?

Comment: @GiselleValladares yes! I added it right where I added the comment about it